# Google webmaster reconsideration requests without manual actions

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console

my site ranking decreases in Google results suddenly about ten days ago. I read many articles about it at support.google.com, but I didn't find the problem.  Also there is no manual action in webmaster tools.

is there any way to ask Google reconsider my site ranking or to say what is the problem of site?

[image]

Background for my site: it is a pharmacy shopping websites. has ~700 product pages and almost all of the description of products is copied from producers website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way contact Google through Webmaster Tools about ranking changes that are caused by their algorithms.   The only way to contact Google is to post in their [Webmaster Central Help --  crawling, indexing, and ranking forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/webmasters/crawling-indexing--ranking).   However, you almost never get a response from Google there.   My experience has been that you get non-helpful (sometimes even antagonistic) responses from others in the community.

In your case, the drop was likely caused by the release of Google's latest [payday Loans 3.0 algorithm](http://searchengineland.com/google-launching-payday-loan-algorithm-3-0-targeting-spammy-queries-week-193821)     The timing of your drop seems to correspond with when they say they launched that algorithm.   That particular algorithm is targeting webspam in the historically spammy niches of PPC (porn, pills, and casino).

Another way that I figure out what went wrong on a specific date because of Google's algorithmic changes is to follow the "Google Updates and SERP Changes" threads in [WebmasterWorld's Google forums](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/).   [Here is the discussion around June 17th](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4676767-4-30.htm) -- there isn't anything super helpful for you there though.  One other person reporting a big drop on the 18th in a non-spammy niche.  When I lose a lot of rankings I generally report it there and hope that other people have a similar problem so that we can collectively figure it out.

[Danny Sullivan from SearchEngineLand.com sat down with Google's Matt Cutts at SMX for the keynote speech this year](http://searchengineland.com/watch-matt-cutts-keynote-smx-advanced-2014-194603).  At one point, Danny requests that Google notify webmasters via Webmaster Tools that their site has been effected by an algorithm with some guidance about what the problem might be and how to go about fixing it.   Matt takes the feedback as a "fair criticism".

Comment: Thanks for your kindly answer. I hope "Google notify webmasters via Webmaster Tools that their site has been effected by an algorithm with some guidance".

Answer (score 2):

> and almost all of the description of products is copied from producers
>   website.

There's your problem. Google does not like duplicate content. In this case, your website is basically just a copy of a more authoritative website.

Have you tried providing original content / descriptions for these products?

A [Google Panda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Panda) update started to roll out on the [20th of May](http://searchengineland.com/google-begins-rolling-panda-4-0-now-192043), so it's possible that it gave your website a bit of a slap.

Personally, I would correct the duplicate content issue and then wait to see if it has any effect.

Comment: my site has same page view about 3 month, with same duplicated content. but 10 days ago, suddenly hits decreased. I don't think it's about duplicate content unless google changes its ranking algorithm in the last month. also I can not provide original descriptoin for ~700 product. Google should consider it!

Comment: "also I can not provide original descriptoin for ~700 product. Google should consider it! " Why not?

Comment: because I have not enough (and expert) employee and time to do this.

Comment: Then I'm sorry, but you're out of luck. If creating a successful website was as easy as copying and pasting content, more people would be doing it.

Comment: it's not copying and pasting. it is a shopping site which shows description of products from producers websites.

Comment: If the description already exists on the producers website and you're displaying the exact same description, then Google will consider it as duplicate content and your website will lose out as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say without performing a deep analysis of your website and your backlink profile.

See following points, it may help:

- Did you recently change your website structure or redesign?
- Did you have many new/lost backlinks in a short period of time (link rapidity)? Use i.e.   http://ahrefs.com and check on the Referring pages graph.
- Check in GoogleWMT if you have backlinks from penalized sites.
- Solve duplicate content issues (i.e. noindex, follow them)
- Avoid too many links on a single page
- Do not publish poor pages with little or no content or just ads, noindex them and do not link to them internally
- Add some useful and not thin content, even if just 1 article a week
- Did you submit a sitemap to G? How many pages? Are them all that useful?

Check those sites for further suggestions and readings:
 - http://www.re1y.com/google-penalties.html , http://www.growler.com/Pro/SEO/aaSEO2/Google-penalties.htm

Hope that helps a bit